Can the word "christen" be used in an entirely non-religious context to describe the naming of something like a building?
Is it appropriate (and culturally sensitive) to use the term christen in a sentence such as:

The building was christened the Stone Center in memory of Dr. Stone, whose research made it possible.

Some dictionaries say that christened means just to name something, while other dictionaries and web searches only bring up the sense of giving a person their Christian name.
Perhaps christening the Stone Center has the second problem that Stone is a last name, not a Christian name?

You've never heard of "christening a ship"?

Merriam-Webster gives several examples. Whether it's culturally-sensitive will vary. I wouldn't use it of a Jewish center. And there's no reason you can't use the verb to name instead (at least in this context).

One might ask whether verbing/genericising names of other revered figures might cause offence.

Did they hit the building with a bottle of champagne?

It is more common and idiomatic to dedicate a building. https://medicine.hsc.wvu.edu/faculty-staff/resources/events-and-ceremony-protocol/#:~:text=Dedication%2FGrand%20Opening%3A,the%20construction%20or%20renovation%20possible.

@StuartF, christen may be more suitable than name is one want to suggest that some formal ceremony was involved.

@EdwinAshworth The alternative is to let them bogart the word.

"Entirely non-religious" is a tough request in a culture and language intimately linked to various religions. Of which this word is a prime example.

I personally don't like it when the secular world borrows sacred words.  "Epiphany" is one example.  Somehow it got borrowed from Christianity to mean the exact opposite (external vs internal revelation.)   JCPenney used a wimpy version of Three Dog Night's "Joy to the World" for their Xmas ad campaign one year. Trying to appease both Xians and non at the same time.  These things are annoying.  So some people would find using "christen" outside of Baptism offensive.  Whether you need to worry about it....shrug.  I don't use "karma" btw.

It is used all the time for the initial naming of a variety of objects, such as ships, buildings, even cars.  Just because a word has its roots in Christianity, does not mean that its usage implies Christianity.
Although I am Indian, I do not regard it as offensive, or "Christian" to use the word christened.

This is probably true, but it's also possible that some people will object.

@DJClayworth: some people object to asserting that the world isn’t flat.

@DJClayworth I've never heard of anyone objecting. It's the common term for when they name a ship and crack a bottle of champagne across its bow, they'll say "I christen thee ". I guess the champagne is considered the secular analogue of holy water.

@Barmar Don't try using it for a mosque.

While the word christening originally referred to the rite in which a person is accepted into the Christian church, (see https://www.etymonline.com/word/christening) these days it is so strongly associated with being given a name that in my (Australian) experience most churches avoid using the word, referring to baptism instead.

https://www.usatoday.com/picture-gallery/travel/cruises/2015/09/10/photo-tour-ship-christenings-with-queen-elizabeth-ii/71992460/

@Rohit_Gupta: "Although I am Indian, I do not regard it as offensive" - Did you mean to say, "Although I am Hindu"? If not, why would your ethnicity potentially make the word offensive?

It's common usage. It will be accepted. Some will find it annoying, especially if the ritual doesn't include something like breaking a bottle of champagne across the bow.
There are probably better words for the purpose, such as inaugurate.
"Real writers rewrite to avoid the problem."

... Good advice.

If you are trying to make it less confusing, I would suggest "named" over "inaugurated".

Depends on context. Naming is not the only thing referred to analogously as christening. Which may be another reason for avoiding the latter word.

Slightly crude, but a good example nonetheless:
In the UK, "to christen the toilet" is to use the bathroom for the first time after moving into a property.
So yes, "christen" can definitely be used to describe non-Christian things.

I think your example is at least partially a humorous analogy to the Christian ceremony, in that it involves splashing something with water.  It's not really about naming, though.

Also, after moving in you can christen the bed (or other pieces of furniture) by making love in it for the first time.

"dedicate (a vessel, building, etc.) ceremonially." - I've christened every toilet I've ever installed; gotta make sure it works.

Back in primary school, when a kid got a new pair of sneakers (usually white coz hundreds of years ago), it was de rigueur for the other kids to 'christen' the new shoes by stomping on them to make them look used.

In my experience, this concept can be applied to first usage of pretty much anything, especially if it involves getting that thing dirty.

Christen/baptize is often used in the sense to name. In this sense it is no different from expressions it is (not) kosher or it is not very Catholic used to designate that something is (not) done according to the rules or with the necessary level of rigor - often in the contexts that have nothing to do with food or religion.

The English christen comes from Greek christos which literally means anointed (originally, with perfumed oil).  The word came to be used in reference to dedicating a ship through the custom of breaking a bottle of wine over the hull of the ship--literally christening (anointing) the ship with wine.
A ship would be christened with wine for some of the same reasons a newborn child would be christened through baptism in the Catholic church.  A child's christening ceremony would also serve as a way of introducing the child to the community.  Christening a ship is similar in that way, but unlike with a baby, christening a ship is not a religious ceremony.
While English speakers might not use the word christen every day, its meaning is not obscure, and christening things (literally by breaking a bottle over them, or figuratively with a small dedication ceremony) would certainly be understood today and would not imply any religious meaning.

Not just the Catholic Church!!

Of course, but I was referring to how the term came to be used in reference to ships.  In those years, the Catholic church was the only game in town.
